# RecyclerView - Use an Arraylist of second activity as data

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a `Recyclerview` wich is populating the data with a resource file that contains an `Arraylist`.

I have a second activity which contains an `Edidtext`and a `Button` that inserts values to another `Arraylist` set in this second activity.

What I need is to use the `Arraylist` on the second activity to populate the `Recyclerview` instead using the data of the resource file.

I've tried to pass the `Arraylist` of one activity to another using `Intent` but didn't get succeed.

**ArrayList in the ViewHolder**

```
public ListAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;

    final String[] countryNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_names);
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < countryNames.length; i++) {
        mItems.add(new LineItem(countryNames[i]));
    }
}
```

**Arraylist in the second activity that I want to use as data**

```
public class DisplayDescActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText descItem;
    public static ArrayList<String> descList = new ArrayList<String>();
...
}
```

Is there a way to do that?

***`Intent` code tried:***

- DisplayDescActivity code:
  On the `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` i've used:

  ```
  Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ListAdapter.class);
  intent1.putStringArrayListExtra("list", descLista);
  startActivity(intent1);
  ```
- ListAdapter code:
  I've tried to use the following code

  ```
  final ArrayList<String> resultArray = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list");
  ```

But the massage **`Cannot resolve method'getIntent()'`** appears.

Comment: You should pass it via Intent, why you didnt succeed? can you post the code you tried?

Comment: @Nanoc I've updated with the Intent code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know form where you are trying to call getIntent, but you need the activity reference, probably you are inside a fragment? then use getActivity().getIntent()

Comment: @Nanoc Actually, I don't know where to call getIntent. I don't have a fragment in my code. Here is the ViewHolder code: [link](https://gist.github.com/jorel89/105f65a0ea567d9f8ad6) , where should I put it?

Comment: As i see in your code you should be able to do ((Activity)mContext).getIntent()

Comment: @Nanoc it seems to work!! Thanks, but now I'm gettin error because i've passed an `ArrayList` and I need to make it an `Array`.

Comment: @Nanoc I've update the code according to the [New code](https://gist.github.com/jorel89/569f9c223b6cf08c98d4) but now i'm getting the following exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.junio.testearray3/com.example.junio.testearray3.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96149/discussion-between-nanoc-and-rooseveltjr).

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the list in activity's `onCreate` event.

```
public class DisplayDescActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText descItem;
    public static ArrayList<String> descList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        descList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list"); 
    }

}
```